# Kafka not stopping consumers when deleting group

Tags: kafka, graylog

I am sending logs from Logstash as the producer to Kafka and then consuming them from Graylog. This works as expected.

However, when stopping the Graylog input, thus sending a LeaveGroup request, the consumer is not unregistered and even when the group is deleted via `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --delete --group graylog2`, Graylog keeps consuming (and is able to do so) even though the Group `graylog2` doesn't exist anymore.

Is this expected behaviour? What's the correct way of unregistering a consumer in this case?